# strange width css issues caused non-fixed layout

Tags: css

I opened other sites, they can't be dragged left and right using touch gesture. It's so strange that my site do the different thing, [image]

I've no problem open it in PC

Comment: What is 'the different thing'? Show some code, describe what you want to reach exactly, explain what you have tried so far and maybe add a fiddle...

Comment: thousand line of css, and I don't know where is the problem. fiddle is not a real ipad, can't show my problem there.

Comment: Your picture showing us seizure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [prevent window from dragging in ios5 mobile browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782005/prevent-window-from-dragging-in-ios5-mobile-browser)

Comment: @C-Link i didn't.. i use touch.. actually I've solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this meta tag?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

width = your main div OR container width

Hope it will helpful to you!!

Answer (score 0):

my bad. It was margin negative! I used it somewhere on div block.